# Storing resultsets in single Array using Groovy/Grails

Tags: grails, groovy

How do I store results for following queries in the same array using groovy?

```
select id from employee where employee_id=100
select id from employee where employee_id=200
select id from employee where employee_id=300
```

Example:

```
def calculate(employee_ids)
{
def result
Sql sql = new Sql(dataSource)

for (employee_id in employee_ids) {    
result = sql.rows("select id from employee where employee_id="+employee_id)
}

sql.close()

return result
}
```

Right now, 'calculate()' function just returns 300 when I pass 100, 200, 300 as 'employee_id'. ('employee_id' is in the form of an array)

How do I get aggregate result when I pass 100, 200, 300 etc. as 'employee_id' into a single array like [100,200,300]?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Be aware that something like `sql.rows("select id from employee where employee_id="+employee_id)` is not SQL injection safe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't really provided enough information.  It isn't clear how you are sending those queries to the database and that might end up being relevant.  If you really need to send them separately then do that and combine the results with something like this...

```
def firstResult = // send query to db...
def secondResult = // send query to db...
def thirdResult = // send query to db...
def combinedResults = firstResult + secondResult + thirdResult
```

But maybe what you really want is to execute a query that is something like this...

```
select id from employee where employee_id in (100, 200, 300)
```

**EDIT:**

You could do something like this...

```
def result = []

for (employee_id in employee_ids) {
    result += sql.rows("select id from employee where employee_id=$employee_id").id
}
```

Comment: Hello Jeff, just updated question. What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: Note that Groovy Strings like the one I show there are SQL injection safe.  The string concatenation you use in your question is not.